# Get broken JSON to CSV python

Tags: python, json, list, csv, for-loop

I am trying to take a poorly formatted JSON and convert it to CSV. Below is a sample of the json:

```
[
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "label": "starttime",
        "field": "starttime",
        "type": "integer"
      },
      {
        "label": "endTime",
        "field": "endTime",
        "type": "integer"
      },
      {
        "label": "duration",
        "field": "duration",
        "type": "integer"
      },
      {
        "label": "metrics",
        "field": "metrics",
        "type": "integer"
      },
      {
        "label": "email",
        "field": "email",
        "type": "string"
      },
     ]
    "results": [
      [
        15949132375,
        15949133139,
        763,
        7,
        "newemail@gmail.com"
      ],
      [
        15949132376,
        15949133140,
        764,
        8,
        "newemail1@gmail.com"
      ],
      [
        15949132377,
        15949133141,
        765,
        9,
        "newemail2@gmail.com"
      ],
      [
        15949132378,
        15949133142,
        766,
        10,
        "newemail3@gmail.com"
      ],
      [
        15949132379,
        15949133143,
        767,
        11,
        "newemail4@gmail.com"
      ],
      [
        15949132380,
        15949133144,
        768,
        12,
        "newemail5@gmail.com"
      ],
      [
        15949132381,
        15949133145,
        769,
        13,
        "newemail6@gmail.com"
      ],
      [
        15949132382,
        15949133146,
        770,
        14,
        "newemail7@gmail.com"
      ],
      [
        15949132383,
        15949133147,
        771,
        15,
        "newemail8@gmail.com"
      ],
    ]
  }
]
```

This is a sample, as the results has a few thousand entries. I need to try and get the values from the upper "fields" section to be the headers and the "results" into the the rows below those headers as they are the data that goes with the "fields"

As I said, the json is not exported correctly and getting it in the correct format with keys is not an option. How can I get this data into a CSV? If not a CSV, how can I get it to format into proper JSON, using the 'fields''label' as the key for each corresponding line in the results?

I have tried just going through pandas and creating a df. Create a list from each data set (fields, label) and results, haven't been able to connect them properly.

Please help?

Comment: Formatting is irrelevant. Syntax is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json file can be read and can be evaluated using "re" module to separate the fields and the results.   The results can then be written to the output csv file

Suggested code :

```
import re
import csv
with open("sample.json") as fptr :
    fstr = fptr.read()
    #jsonStr = eval(fstr)
    fields = re.findall ('"fields": (\[.*?\])', fstr, re.M+re.S+re.I)
    fields = eval(fields[0])
    headers = [ f['label'] for f in fields]
    results = re.findall ('"results": (\[.*\]).*}', fstr, re.M+re.S+re.I)
    results = eval(results[0])
    # print (fields, results, headers)

with open ("output.csv", "w", newline="") as fptr :
    recordWrite = csv.writer(fptr, dialect='excel')
    recordWrite.writerow(headers)
    recordWrite.writerows(results)
```

Note : Looking at the json above, it would be possible to evaluate the whole file content using "eval" instead of using "re".   The only change needed would be to add a comma after the list ends and the "fields" starts.